# Merging text file directories

Tags: text-processing, git, c, source

I have two directories: Libc-825 and Libc-1044. Imagine that version 1044 is newer, but buggy. Is there a way to merge these file trees? I have there C sources with not so big differences. I have heard of using git for such purposes.

Edit: I want to get diffs of all the files where names clash, to fix bugs manually

Comment: What would you want to achieve with the merge? It sounds like you want the merge to "magically" fix the bugs in 1044 while keeping its functionality. Please [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/258413/edit) to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `diff` to generate a patch with new, old and conflicting files.

```
diff -Naur Libc-825 Libc-1044
```

The flags state `-N` treat missing files as new, `-a` all files are text, `-u` show lines before and after diff for easier identification and `-r` recursive. You can then apply the patch to the old directory and get the merged results.